# I need a function to choose the best model included in my dataframe in Python

Tags: python, function, dataframe, model

I have a dataframe with 3 columns: model, dependent variable (y) and f1_score.

I need a function to choose the best model for each dependent variable (y). 
The best model is the model whose f1_score has the greatest value.

Can you help me please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"model": ["a", "b", "a", "c"], "feature": [1, 1, 2,2], "f1":[0.95, 0.98, 0.7, 0.75]})
pd.pivot_table(df, index="feature", values="model", aggfunc=max)
        model
feature
1           b
2           c
```